# How to stop Microsoft Cognitive TTS synthesizer?

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using [MS Cognitive TTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech-Service/text-to-speech) Speech API. Once the synthesizer starts synthesizing, how can I stop it?

Comment: What is your implementation?

Comment: I took the C++ sample for Windows from the "https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/cpp/windows/console" and I used the latest version 1.6.0.

I tried different approaches, with push and pull audio output streams and also with handling the events but no luck. I am not even sure if this is implemented in the text-to-speech API at all. At least docs are not saying anything about it.

Comment: In speech-to-text when input audio stream is used and then closed in the middle of the recognition, recognition is stopped. For text-to-speech there is no equivalent close function on output audio stream or some similar mechanism. Or, at least, I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

As for now (speech SDK version 1.8.0), stopping synthesizing is not support. You can stop playing the synthesized audio instead.